# How to trigger function after using .loaddata

Tags: php, jquery, loaddata

I am wondering why i cannot execute a jquery function on a button loaded with .loaddata function.

```
<div id="products"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(event) {
    loadData(1,'default');
});

function loadData(page,type){
    var base = '<?php echo $sr_class->baseURL();?>';
    $.ajax
    ({
        type: "GET",
        url: base+"includes/module/loadProduct.php",
        data: {page:page,type:type},
        success: function(msg)
        {
            console.info(msg);
            $("#products").html(msg);
        }
    });
}
$('.addcart').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var proid = $(this).attr('proid');
    var base = '<?php echo $sr_class->baseURL();?>';
    $.post(base+'includes/module/addtocart.php',{p_id:proid, p_qty:1},function(result){
        location.reload();
    })
});

</script>
```

the 'msg' return from loadData function is :

```
<p><a proid="ABCD1001" class="btn btn-success addcart" role="button"> ABCD1001</a></p>
```

When i click the button, it did not execute the function.

Comment: if the html code dynamicaly loaded, you must define your function for this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're using `.click()` instead of `.on()`. The `click()` binding you're using is called a "direct" binding which will only attach the handler to elements that already exist. It won't get bound to elements created in the future. To do that, you'll have to create a "delegated" binding by using `on()`.

From the [documentation of `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time.

So bind `.addcart` element with `.on()` like this:

```
$(document).on('click','.addcart',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var proid = $(this).attr('proid');

    $.post('<?php echo $sr_class->baseURL();?>includes/module/addtocart.php',{p_id:proid, p_qty:1},function(result){
        location.reload();
    })
});
```

Comment: @hafizyBaharudin You're welcome! Glad I could help. ;-)